# Am I making a fatal error with this simplification?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, education, flow, volume

I'm teaching a grade 9 math course that deals with volumes of pyramids, cones, prisms, and cylinders and I wanted to come up with an interesting situation that uses the 1/3 volume factor. I know that fluids are tricky but I was wondering if the logic I've used here is a valid simplification or not? It's fine if they learn more details should they take physics some other time, but I don't want to tell them anything wrong. Here's the example:

> "Water flowing through a cylindrical hose flows through a cone-shaped spout at the end. If water is flowing through the hose at 3 cm/s, how fast is it flowing through the cone tip? You can assume that water cannot be compressed to take up less volume.

> Answer: The volume of the spout is one-third of the volume of the hose. As the water gets to the end of the hose, the water is squished into a smaller space. So, the water must flow faster to compensate. Logically, the water must flow through the cone 3 times as fast. So, water should be passing through the cone at a rate of 9 cm/s.
>
> This 9cm/s should be considered an average rate. In reality, the water coming out of the tiny tip would be moving faster, but water at the base of the cone where it is the widest would be traveling more slowly."

EDIT: Thanks so much for helping me think through this problem, everyone. I enjoyed reading all of your answers and am grateful you took the time to write at such length. I am going to shelve this problem as is for the grade 9s, but if I do get a chance to pose it with another age group then I'll be able to do it properly then.

Comment: Consider that the hose and the spout may have different lengths such that the 1/3 volume factor does not apply. As long as we have a flow rate, changing the length of the hose will not affect anything that happens at the spout. So the volume factor cannot be relevant here, unfortunately!

Comment: The problem as stated is somewhat ambiguous without a drawing.  Does the cone base attach to the hose or does the cone tip attach to the hose?  What is the diameter of the hose, the diameter of the cone base and the diameter of the hole in the cone tip?  Also, without knowing the continuity equation, the students are going to have a difficult time understanding the question's solution, and that equation guarantees that the water's velocity in the cone is not constant.  This is a difficult example for a 9th grader to comprehend.

Comment: Though this particular concept may not quite fit with your intention, note that it presents an excellent opportunity to discuss the fact that "average" is an overloaded term.  Do you mean the average over the length of the cone, or the average over the *volume* of the cone, or the average over time for a single fluid parcel? Michael's excellent answer illustrates how each of these might be computed.

Comment: For 9th graders learning about geometry, I would maybe try to see if I can find a cylindrical and a conical container, both of which have the same height and same opening radius. Then use water to pour to prove that the cylinder's volume goes into the cone's volume 3 times.

Comment: I just want to say, I think it's wonderful that you are thinking of interesting problems to pose, putting in great effort, and even vetting those problems by asking online strangers! This one might not be perfect, but I hope you keep it up :). Maybe you can do something with the volume of fuel/burn duration of a rocket/firework with cylindrical bottom and conical top, or a sand-filled hourglass, and pretend like the flow rate is constant.

Comment: Glasses with cylindrical outsides and conical insides (historically used to provide bar patrons with less beverage than they thought they were getting, context may need to be adapted for age appropriateness) provide a cylinder/cone volume comparison without needing to consider flow rate.

Comment: @KingLogic Did you mean the cone's volume goes into the cylinders volume three times?

Comment: @TCooper cone volume = cylinder volume / 3, or cone can be completely filled and pour into cylinder, 3 times.

Comment: @KingLogic Right, I guess your wording in the first comment threw me off. I've always considered the phrase "x's volume(v) 'goes into' y's v m times" to be imply xvm = yv. I've never really seen 'goes into' used with, what to me, is the opposite meaning. 2 goes into 6 3 times, but 6 doesn't go into 2 3 times, no?

Comment: @TCooper yeah sorry my bad for causing confusion, I meant Cylinder volume / 3 = Cone volume

Comment: @KingLogic Sorry to be so pedantic, I push because I never know if there’s specific terminology used in a field I’m relatively foreign to - I didn’t want to exclude that could be a very common phrasing, and for good reason I couldn’t see.

Answer (score 13):

That's not right, unfortunately. The principle governing this situation is the continuity equation, which says that the total flow rate past any given point is constant.  Since the flow rate is given by the flow *speed* $v$ times the cross-sectional area of the hose $A$, one has that
$$v_1 A_1 = v_2 A_2$$
for any two points along the flow.  In particular, the velocity of the water coming out through the nozzle is
$$v_{spout} = \frac{\big(3 \mathrm{cm/s} \big)A_{hose}}{A_{spout}}$$
where $A_{hose}$ is the cross-sectional area of the hose and $A_{spout}$ is the cross-sectional area of the aperature at the end of the nozzle.

> The term average might be used too loosely. But, wouldn't it still be true that after 1 second of flow, the equivalent amount of water in the cylindrical portion of the hose would need to escape the cone shape at the end. And that the cone would have to expel its volume 3 times to match the volume in the cylinder portion?

Yes.  There is a sense in which the 9 cm/s is a relevant figure. If you divide the water within the cone into many tiny little parcels, compute the speed of each parcel, and then average them all together, the average of all of those speeds approaches 9 cm/s as the area of the aperture at the end of the cone goes to zero. In particular it is not the velocity at the half-way point of the cone (in fact, it is the velocity at the point $1-1/\sqrt{3}\approx 42.26\%$ of the way from the base to the tip).

If that's what you're asking your students to compute, the volume of a cylinder vs. the volume of a cone with the same length and base area is a reasonable shortcut to the solution. However, for grade 9 students I fear that the question would be completely opaque.

Your intent appears to be to get them to divide the volume of a cylinder by the volume of a cone. It is in principle possible to devise a question to which that is the shortest path to a solution, but my personal opinion is that this route would simply confuse them, and that any attempt at explanation would ultimately lead you to "look, just divide these two volumes ... " which defeats the point of having a creative question.

But then again, you're their instructor, so that's a call you'd have to make.

Comment: And thus if $A_{\mathrm{spout}}$ actually goes to zero (a perfectly sharp tip with an infinitesimal hole) then the velocity goes to infinity

Comment: Yes, I tried to address this at the end when I write "This 9cm/s should be considered an average rate. In reality, the water coming out of the tiny tip would be moving faster, but water at the base of the cone where it is the widest would be traveling more slowly." The term average might be used too loosely.

But, wouldn't it still be true that after 1 second of flow, the equivalent amount of water in the cylindrical portion of the hose would need to escape the cone shape at the end. And that the cone would have to expel its volume 3 times to match the volume in the cylinder portion?

Comment: To find the average, we have to integrate $v_{\mathrm{spout}}$ from the radius of the cylinder $r_0$ to the radius of the hole at the spout, $r_s$. The integral is thus $3\mathrm{cm/s}\int_0^{r_s} \frac{\pi r_0^2}{\pi(r_0-x)^2}dx = 3\mathrm{cm/s}\frac{r_0r_s}{r_0-r_s}$

Comment: Yes, it's true that the volume of the cone is 1/3 of the volume of the cylinder of the same height. But this does not follow from the water flow situation. The speed depends only on the cross sectional area. You can make the nozzle profile any shape (parabolic, hyprbolic, whatewer) but the rate of flow could be the same if the cross section area of the exit end is the same.  And besides, you are trying to explain something by relating to something else which is probably less familiar to the students.

Comment: @rdotrose I have edited my answer to address your follow-up.

Comment: @J.Murray:  Note that to get the desired answer you need to take the *time-average* of a water molecule's speed as it goes through the nozzle.  Your description of how to average the speed sounds more like the average of the speed over the distance (which is very very large.)  [See my answer.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/658724/81133)

Comment: (Though now that I think about it, the *volume* average would be another way to do it, and might give the same thing as the time-average.  I will edit my answer shortly to reflect this.)

Answer (score 9):

1. The tip cannot come to a point - otherwise the water cannot escape from its end -  so actually its shape is a truncated cone also known as a [conical frustrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum).
2. You say

> If water is flowing through the hose at 3 cm/s, how fast is it flowing through the cone tip?

This wording is ambiguous. I have taken this to mean "how fast is the water leaving the end of the tip". I see other answers have used different interpretations.

3. The ratio of the speed of the water in the hose pipe and the speed of the water leaving the end of the tip depends on their respective cross-sectional areas. The water leaving the end of tip only travels three times as fast as in the hose if the cross-sectional area at the end of the tip is one third that of the hose. The volume (and, indeed, the exact shape) of the tip are irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

This does work out to be correct, but there's a pitfall hiding in the question in the idea of what the "average speed" is, and (IMO) the subtleties involved make it a bad fit for a ninth-grade math class.

To be a bit more realistic, let's assume that the nozzle is a frustum with height $h$, a radius $r_0$ at the base and radius $\epsilon r_0$ (with $\epsilon \ll 1$) at the tip.  Assuming the frustum tapers uniformly, the radius of the cone at a distance $x$ from the base would be $r = r_0 + xr_0(\epsilon - 1)/h $, and the speed of the water a distance $x$ from the base would be
$$
v = v_0 \frac{r_0^2}{(r_0 + x(\epsilon r_0 - r_0)/h)^2} = \frac{v_0}{(1 + x (\epsilon-1)/h)^2}.
$$

This means that we can calculate the *distance-averaged* speed of the water over the length of the nozzle.  This would be what we would get if we stuck a large number of evenly-spaced flowmeters along the length of the nozzle and then averaged their readings.   It works out to be
$$
\langle v \rangle_x = \frac{v_0}{h} \int_0^h \frac{dx}{(1 + x (\epsilon-1)/h)^2} = \frac{v_0}{h} \left( \frac{h}{\epsilon} \right) = \frac{v_0}{\epsilon}.
$$
We can see that this is *not* equal to $3 v_0$ as your argument would predict.

But wait!  Maybe if we take the average over the *volume* of the nozzle, things will work better.  We can accomplish this by "weighting" the above integral by the cross-sectional area of the nozzle.  This *does* work out;  we have
$$
\langle v \rangle_V = \frac{v_0}{V} \int_0^h \frac{\pi r_0^2 (1 + x (\epsilon-1)/h)^2 dx}{(1 + x (\epsilon-1)/h)^2} = \frac{\pi h v_0 r_0^2}{\frac{1}{3} \pi h r_0^2(1 + \epsilon + \epsilon^2)} = \frac{3 v_0}{1 + \epsilon + \epsilon^2}.
$$
which does in fact approach $3 v_0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Alternately, we can also try to calculate the average speed of a water molecule as it passes through the nozzle.  The time taken for the water molecule to pass through this nozzle will be
$$
\Delta t = \int_{x=0}^{x=h} dt = \int_0^h \frac{dx}{v} = \frac{h}{3 v_0} (1 + \epsilon + \epsilon^2)
$$
and the *time-averaged* speed of the water molecule will then be the distance traveled $h$ divided by $\delta t$, or
$$
\langle v \rangle_t = \frac{3 v_0}{1 + \epsilon + \epsilon^2},
$$
as we found above by the volume average.

So if you define "average speed" to be distance traveled over time taken, then your answer is correct.  To be fair, this is how "average speed" is defined in physics, so it's [technically correct.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZEuWJ4muYc)   But it's also true that the speed of the water gets very very very large for $\epsilon \ll 1$;  for a proper cone ($\epsilon = 0$), it is moving infinitely fast as it exits the nozzle.  You might get a student asking you "if the water is moving infinitely fast as it leaves the cone, how can the average speed be finite?"  I'm not sure that there's a good answer to this question without breaking out the calculus like I did above, and presumably ninth-graders aren't ready for that.

(This idea that an infinite speed at one point in a trip is compatible with a finite average speed over that trip is more clearly (?) illustrated in the old chestnut of a brain-teaser.  A person needs to drive a 10-mile journey.  They run into traffic over the first 5 miles and only drive at 30 miles per hour over that distance.  How fast must they drive for the remaining 5 miles to average 60 miles per hour over the whole trip?  The intuitive answer of 90 mph is, of course, wrong, but [very smart people have reportedly fallen into that trap.](https://books.google.com/books?id=-UMCDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=An+old+clattery+auto+is+to+drive+a+stretch+of+2+miles,+up+and+down+a+hill,+/%5C.+Because+it+is+so+old,&source=bl&ots=K_QenT_w_Q&sig=ACfU3U2Q8jqqS5w0HfFB9iW2q2PqP2ULzA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB8urklqnyAhWZKs0KHdV8BKUQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=An%20old%20clattery%20auto%20is%20to%20drive%20a%20stretch%20of%202%20miles%2C%20up%20and%20down%20a%20hill%2C%20%2F%5C.%20Because%20it%20is%20so%20old%2C&f=false))

Comment: Nice. I like the presentation of the different ways one might interpret the word "average" - though this problem as stated may not be appropriate for 9th graders, it is an excellent opportunity to discuss this linguistic / technical ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different tack that you can take to ask a similar question and arrive at the correct final concept (see the other excellent answers for directly answering the original question).

> Question: Water flowing through a cylindrical hose flows through a cone-shaped spout of height $h$ at the end. If water is flowing through the hose at a constant rate (water volume per unit time) and it takes three seconds for the final length $h$ of the hose to be filled, how much more time will it take to fill the cone tip? You can assume that water cannot be compressed to take up less volume.

> Answer: The volume of the spout is one third of the volume of the hose. Since the water is flowing at a constant rate, it will take one third of the time: one second.